# Linked Table Manager does not work

Tags: microsoft-access-2003

I have Microsoft Access 2003 installed.

When I use the [Linked Table Manager](https://office.microsoft.com/en-in/access-help/view-refresh-or-change-the-file-name-and-path-for-linked-tables-mdb-HP005187623.aspx) to link to a back end it does not work. There are no error messages. It just flashes and keeps asking begging for the location of the BE which I provided already.

Comment: By any chance do you have multiple version of access installed?

Comment: It sounds like the linked table manager is running, but prompting you repeatedly for the back end. This is usually an indication that you've selected multiple tables to relink and one of them is not found in the back end.